# How to get a by alphabetical order in the select column of sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this code for selecting the brand name but the brand name in the select box is not sort by alphabetical order on HTML. So I want to get the select box by alphabetical order.

```
<?
$sql = "select * from zhaq_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies where 
attribute_name='brand'";
$result = sql_query($sql);
     while($row = sql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo make_pa_option($row['attribute_name'],$product_opt); 
         }
?>
```

Please help me with any answers. Thank you.

Comment: What is the column name for the brand name ?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using MySQL's `ORDER BY` clause? Also, generally speaking, it is good form (and makes more efficient queries) to explicitly list only the columns you need to in the SELECTion list. _Typical example, imagine if an image BLOB was added to the table; then every query on that table that used `SELECT *` would be needlessly retrieving a bunch of images.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require an ORDER BY clause at the end of your SQL query, to order the resultset by the column containing the brand name...

`select * from zhaq_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies where 
attribute_name='brand' ORDER BY {column_to_order_by}`

...simply replace {column_to_order_by} with the column name.

Comment: Thank you and I'll try to replace instead of {} but it is a little bit difficult to find the column name of the brand of the attribute in woocommerce.